Android Studio: how to tell which build type I am using?
I making an app using Kotlin. I read about build types here: https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants. That page states:

Android Studio automatically creates the debug and release build types.


Although the debug build type doesn't appear in the build configuration file, Android Studio configures it with debuggable true.

This page shows how to set settings for each build type, but how do I tell which build type I am currently using? There is no section explaining that. The debug type exists, but doesn't appear in build.gradle, so how am I supposed to know if it's selected?
My build.gradle is as follows. I manually added isCrunchPngs = false for performance (I am have already crunched them all manually, no un-crunched version exists in the project). I have another question about that, which I post separately here: Is isCrunchPngs = false set up properly here?
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.vyze"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.vyze"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            isCrunchPngs = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.firebase.firestore)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}


You can see what build you are using with the "Build Variants" button (usually in the lower left corner of the Android Studio screen), and can also use that to change types with the "Active Build Variant" dropdown.
By default when you build and run on an emulator it runs the "debug" variant, and when you build a signed APK bundle to deploy it builds the "release" variant.


Slightly different place for me, I had to go to the top menu > Build > Select Build Variant, but this worked! Thank you!

Glad it worked. I probably selected something to pin that panel button to the left there at some point...
